# Not able to send draft envelope with two roles(Signer, Approver)

Tags: docusignapi

We have created a draft envelope using a template with Rest API. That template has 2 roles. Role-1 is assigned Identity as "Email" and "Digital Certificate" and role-2 is assigned with "Email". Role-1 fill the envelop form and sign and Role-2 just sign the form as an approver.

We didn't change anything in the template from many days. Using same template we were able to create envelope till last week. It's look like some recent code checkin to the docusign effected this and we are not able to create an envelope with two roles. Same problem is there in both Production and Demo docusign sites

We have few more templates with single role with Identity as "Email" and "Digital Certificate". We don't have any problems in sending the envelope in this case.

We are trying to reach with docusign support from last 2 days through mails. But no one has responded regarding this("DocuSign Case #: 01999769") This is 3rd issue we are facing from the docusign since last 10days. Our product release is getting delayed because of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using DocuSign Digital Express, OpenTrust, or SAFE certificates?

Once one signer has signed with a digital certificate, all subsequent signers for the same transaction (envelope) must also use digital certificates.

Docs: See the Limitations section of the [DocuSign Digital Certificates Quick Start.](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/quick-start-requiring-digital-certificates.pdf)

Regarding API support: At this time, DocuSign standard support does not include development assistance with the APIs. (This is common throughout the industry.) If you want paid API support, you need to engage DocuSign Professional Services.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I am using DocuSign "Digital Express" Certificates.

We are communicating with docusign team regarding this. Everything was working since last 8 months and till  27/Aug/2015. Some update is checked-in to docusign which created this problem to us